# When using the onUpdate function in Firebase, how do I retrieve the a child of the returned snapshot?

Tags: typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I have the bellow code which used to run using a .onCreate, I changed it to a .onUpdate and now the .child() lines have errors indicating I cannot perform the action. How do I proceed? I need to access these values.

```
   export const sendNewMessageNotification = functions.database
  .ref('/ChatTimelines/{uid}/{chatID}/')
  .onUpdate((snapshot, context) => {
    //.onCreate
    const uid = context.params.uid
    const otherUID = snapshot.child("otherUID").val()//error
    const message = snapshot.child("lastMessage").val()//error
    snapshot
  
    //addNewLikeNotif(uid, newLikerUID, mediaNumber, timeStamp, postID)
    return sendNewMessageNotificationFunc(uid, otherUID, message) 
  })
```

Update: Update2 this did not work

(change, context)

```
 let snapshot = change.after.val()
const otherUID = snapshot.child("otherUID").val()
const message = snapshot.child("lastMessage").val()
```

Comment: Use onWrite instead

Comment: @JayCodist same result

Comment: I think  `snapshot.parent.child("otherUID").val();` should work. Does it not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `onUpdate` then you need to do the following:

```
  .onUpdate((snapshot, context) => {
    const uid = context.params.uid
    const otherUID = snapshot.after.child("otherUID").val();
    const message = snapshot.after.child("lastMessage").val();
```

Check the docs:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff#sdk_changes_by_trigger_type